# Rails 3 - multiple level nesting - getting Uninitialized Constant Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to both programming and Ruby on Rails. I'm just trying with a sample 2 level deep nesting. When I followed Ryan's Scraps (http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) for 1 level deep nesting everything well and good but when I extended for 2 level deep I'm getting

```
NameError in ParentsController#new
uninitialized constant Child::Grandchild
```

My models are like this

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :grandchildren
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandchildren
end

class GrandChild < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :child
end
```

And my controller : new method for parent is ->

```
def new
  @parent = Parent.new
  2.times do 
    child = @parent.children.build  
    2.times {child.grandchildren.build}
  end


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @parent }
  end
end
```

Don't know what's the error , when I modified the models into

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :through => :grandchildren
  has_many :grandchildren
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandchildren, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :grandchildren
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandchildren
end

class GrandChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :child
end
```

then I'll get following error-- `uninitialized constant Parent::Grandchild`..

I Don't know its a silly mistake or what...

Thanks

---

I have edited my question which is my real requirement. Instead of creating parent, children and grandchildren at a time as mentioned earlier I want to create parent first then child and grandchild together. I have edited the above code as mentioned below,

My model:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :children
has_many :grand_children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grand_children, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent
has_many :grand_children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grand_children
end

class GrandChild < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent
belongs_to :child
end
```

My children controller -new method:

```
    def new
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
child = Child.new
child.grand_children.build
respond_to do |format|
format.html # new.html.erb
format.xml  { render :xml => @child }
end
end
```

My children _form template is

```
<%= form_for([@parent, @parent.children.build]) do |form|  %>  
<div>
<%= form.label :name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :sex %><br />
<%= form.text_field :sex %>
</div>
<div>
<%= form.fields_for :grand_children do |grand_child_form| %>
<%= render :partial => "grand_children/form", :locals => { :form => grand_child_form}     %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here I'm not getting any error as such but when I select new child the grand_child is not appearing,

```
 <%= form.fields_for :grand_children do |grand_child_form| %>
  <%= render :partial => "grand_children/form", :locals => { :form => grand_child_form} %>
<% end %>
```

is not getting reflected at all .

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you're instantiating grandchildren you're trying to do it with a child which hasn't been saved. This won't work. Google for double nested forms you'll find tutorials on this. I'd write more but it's Sunday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your error is your association name,  but I don't have a rails terminal to try it on.

```
has_many :grandchildren
```

should be

```
has_many :grand_children
```

GrandChild is camel cased, and would be grand_child underscored, and grand_children when tableized.

I believe rails is using the underscore/tableize methods when doing it's associations, if you're ever having this problem again with an association, take your class name in a console and do

```
"GrandChild".tableize
"GrandChild".underscore
```

That will give you your association names.